# Ipv6 address format from struct.unpack

Tags: python, struct

What would be the way to unpack and map to ipv6 address. I'm currently doing the following

```
In [3]: struct.unpack("!h",'*\x00')
Out[3]: (10752,)

In [5]: ipaddress.IPv6Address(10752)
Out[5]: IPv6Address(u'::2a00')
```

but of course the end result i wish for is 2a00:: , i was expecting IPv6Address to return it but i'm missing something.

What i'm currently doing is unpacking as sting then to hex and append :: .

```
In [14]: struct.unpack("!2s",'*\x00')
Out[14]: ('*\x00',)

In [15]: '*\x00'.encode("hex")
Out[15]: '2a00'

then append to hex and append 

In [16]: '*\x00'.encode("hex")+'::'
Out[16]: '2a00::'
```

Comment: I'm not following why you expect `2a00`, that would be `55827575822966466661959896531774472192` (so shift it with 112 bits) that maps on `2a00::`, since you could say that an IP address is "little endian"

Comment: thanks for that. was hopping rather than expecting to be honest.what would be the way to shift this ? any module i can use.

Comment: Just use binary operators, so `ipaddress.IPv6Address(10752<<112)`, but note that this trick will only work for numbers up to 2^16 (65'536), since otherwise the value is "too large".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP adress converts what we could see as a binary number into a 128-bit representation with hexadecimal numbers (and some other logic to compress zero sequenes).

The number `10752` is equivalent to:

```
00        00        00        00        00        00        00  (hex)
00        00        00        00        00        2a        00

00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  (bin)
00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00101010  00000000
```

or thus with colons in between:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:2a00
```

and this is actually what you get. IPv6 addresses use double colons to strip of sequences of zero.

If we shift the value however 112 places up (128-16), we thus get:

```
2a        00        00        00        00        00        00  (hex)
00        00        00        00        00        00        00

00101010  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  (bin)
00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
```

which is thus:

```
2a00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

so we can obtain the desired output with:

```
>>> ipaddress.IPv6Address(10752<<112)
IPv6Address('2a00::')
```

Note that the above however will only work if the data is less than *2<sup>16</sup>=65'536*, since otherwise it takes more than 16 bits, and then the value is too large to get represented by an IPv6 address.